# JWT signature is different between response and request headers

Tags: http, go, cookies, jwt

I'm implementing an authentication API that uses JWT which is then stored in a cookie. The cookie is set correctly in the response header and it seems so in the request header. The problem is the signature of the `access_token` in the response and the one in the request are different. Therefore, upon validation, it fails.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, they're different. I'm confused why it's changed in the request header. Is this an intended behavior? If so, how do I put it back to its original signature? This is how I'm setting the cookie

```
atCookie := new(http.Cookie)
atCookie.Name = "access_token"
atCookie.Value = "my-access-token"
```

This is how I read it

```
c.Cookie("access_token").Value
```

I'm using https://github.com/golang-jwt/jwt. I think I followed everything from the documentation. I'm using Echo as the framework. I've been trying to figure this out for hours it would nice if someone can help me.

**UPDATE**
Turns out I just needed to set the cookie path.

```
atCookie.Path = "/"
```

Not sure if this correct though but it's able to save the cookie in the browser. It wasn't sending any cookie to the server at all. The `Cookie` header value is a mess as it's littered with cookies from other tabs so it added to the confusion.

Comment: Have a look at how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry will do that...

Answer (score 1):

The logs that you're showing come from a request to your login endpoint. You send one access token in a cookie to that endpoint, perform login, then issue a new access token and set it in the response header. I think this is a perfectly normal behaviour.

Comment: Yeah. I'm new to this whole setup. I guess the issue is the response header's cookie is not syncing with the request header's. So on the first login, no cookie is set in the request header and it will fail. Subsequently, the request header's cookie will always be invalid as it's always going to be the old one. Obviously, I’m not understanding something.

Comment: When you send a request to the login endpoint then the request cookie should be ignored by your server. When someone tries to log in you assume they don't have any cookie yet. Once they logged in, you send the cookie in the response. Then, when calling other endpoints, the cookie will be sent to your server, and those other endpoint should validate that token. The login endpoint should not validate the token.